# ¿Cómo concatenar varios audios utilizando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

Quiero concatenar varios audios de una carpeta. Probé este código con dos archivos de audio.

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import librosa.display

example_audio = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
x, sr = librosa.load('/Users/ottocastro/Desktop/Join/a.wav', duration=5)
y, sr = librosa.load('/Users/ottocastro/Desktop/Join/b.wav', duration=5)

z = np.append(x,y)
librosa.output.write_wav('AudioFinal.wav', z, sr)
```

Este código funciona pero lo que deseo que haga el código y no sé cómo hacerlo es que lea y etiquete cada archivo de .wav que tengo en un carpeta para después revolverlos.

En resument lo que deseo que el código haga es:

1. Que el código lea varios archivos .wav de una carpeta.
2. Una vez leídos, los pegue uno con otro creando un solo archivo de audio.
3. Que tenga opción de revolverlos con random o shuffle y que me los vuelva a concatenar esos pedazos desordenados creando un solo archivo de audio.

Comment: Hola Otto, gracias por traducir la pregunta (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar una nueva medalla). Sobre el código compartido: ¿Recibes algún error al ejecutar ese código? ¿cómo no funciona? Saludos.

Comment: Genial!!! Ya edité mi problema e incluí que no hace el código y qué deseo que haga. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para el ejemplo usé archivos wav de 16 bit de 44mhz.

```
from os import listdir, system, remove, path
from random import shuffle as desordenar
import wave


datos = []
RUTA = "C:/audio wave/"
NOMBRE_ARCHIVO = "salida.wav"

if path.exists(RUTA+NOMBRE_ARCHIVO) is True:
  remove(RUTA+NOMBRE_ARCHIVO)

archivos = listdir() # Obtiene todos los archivos del directorio
desordenar(archivos) # Desordena el contenido de la lista

for archivo in archivos:
  if archivo[-3:].upper() == "WAV":
    # Se filtra, por los archivos con extensión WAV
    onda = wave.open(RUTA+archivo, "rb")

    # Se recorre la lista agregando las propiedades de cada archivo, en la posición datos[X][],
    # y el contenido del archivo, en la posición datos[][X]
    datos.append([onda.getparams(), onda.readframes(onda.getnframes())])
    onda.close()

try:
  salida = wave.open(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO, "wb")

  # Se establecen las propiedades del archivo de salida.
  salida.setparams(datos[0][0])

  # Por cada objeto dentro de datos, se escriben "anexa" su información
  for indice in range(len(datos)):
    salida.writeframes(datos[indice][1])
  salida.close()
  system(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO)
except Exception as err:
  print(err)
```